# How to manage state between React router and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have data that I'd be fetching from an api stored as `items`,

```
{ '001': {id: '001', name:'foo',color:'blue' }}, '002': { id: '002',name:'bar',color:'orange' }, '003': { id: '003',name:'baz',color:'pink' }}
```

which would be added to my redux state tree and would determine what's rendered on a particular path.  For example, going to `/foo` would directed a user to a page with a background color of its associated color, `blue`.  I have some code I started on trying to implement this but am confused as to how I'd coordinate this.  I was looking at possibly doing something like running `Object.keys(props.items).find(id => props.items[id].name === match.params.name)`, but figure that this wouldn't be a super scalable solution and would lead to a loss of the O(1) lookup afforded by having an object.  The code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n562wzzmkm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `name` property as the path to each item, then the method of matching (searching/finding) that you mentioned is, in my mind, probably the best option. Because `name` is down one level for each item, we have to search all of our items for a match to `match.params.id` `onClick` in order to render a `<Detail/>`s component with the correct item's data.

But, if you're open to it, I'd propose you use each item's top-level key (i.e. `001`, `002`, `003`) as the the `to` prop for your mapped `<Link/>` components. In that way, we can still achieve O(1) by using that method in conjunction with the `render` prop for your `<Route/>` that handles rendering a `<Detail/>` component with the chosen item's data. We'll still do the lookup using `match.params.id`, but we'll only have to be looking at the top level of `items` to find the correct item and successfully set the correct background color.

The code in question below and a fork of your CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xl8von46nw?fontsize=14

```
/**** Setting each to prop equal to the top-level id for each item ****/

  <ul>
    {Object.keys(items).map(id => (
      <li key={id}>
        <Link to={id}>item {items[id].name}</Link>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>

/**** I used connect() in routes.js to access items ****/

  <Route
    path="/:id"
    render={({ match }) => (
      <Detail
        item={items[match.params.id]}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Hope that helps or is an acceptable solution!